# Firebase getValue() not retrieving boolean correctly?

Tags: android, firebase, boolean, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble with a firebase call that I want to compare if the value is simply true or false. Here is my attempt:

```
   Firebase followingRef = currentUserPath.child("/following");
   followingRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            firebaseRef.child("people/" + dataSnapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    Boolean isFollowing = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    if(isFolloiwng) {
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        user.setUserId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        application.getFollowingRecyclerViewAdapter().add(user, application.getFollowingRecyclerViewAdapter());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    ...//OnChildChanged,Moved,etc... no code in here
```

At the path I want to reference in `currentUserPath.child("following");` it looks like this:

EDIT: Replace Picture with actual JSON:

```
 "users" : {
    "10206287838487450" : {
      "following" : {
        "10208425049208936" : true,
        "107214969710378" : false,
        "1789986447904975" : true
      },
      "id" : "ae80f030-dea0-4909-944f-0e490847b6ab",
      "name" : "Stephen",
      "posts" : {
        "-KN_oJAgTNJHwJbqY3qk" : true,
        "-KN_oN9_Xmw5ULnBRYM7" : true,
        "-KN_obYGug9Tdrzufbqc" : true,
        "-KNefMk2nX0sOsUx0btx" : true
      },
      "userId" : "10206287838487450"
    },

  "people" : {
    "10206287838487450" : {
      "id" : "9e7ee838-a60a-4588-bc1c-93b98f74356d",
      "name" : "Bob",
      "userId" : "10206287838487450"
    },
    "10208425049208936" : {
      "id" : "fe6f97e3-0efb-4afb-a322-a1c586f75fb7",
      "name" : "Jack",
      "userId" : "10208425049208936"
    },
    "107214969710378" : {
      "id" : "ae80f030-dea0-4909-944f-0e490847b6ab",
      "name" : "Rick",
      "userId" : "107214969710378"
    },
    "108421236267392" : {
      "id" : "c72b35d9-380b-4552-8b05-7426d378fa14",
      "name" : "Tommy",
      "userId" : "108421236267392"
    },
    "1112460595485164" : {
      "id" : "383692f0-0aba-4d29-afb8-80beefe678c6",
      "name" : "Stanley",
      "userId" : "1112460595485164"
    },
    "1789986447904975" : {
      "id" : "1ae43255-c040-4b1e-959e-fcdf03e13a45",
      "name" : "Link",
      "userId" : "1789986447904975"
    }
  },
```

I'm very confused because every time I try to cast the `dataSnapshot.getValue()` to a Boolean, I always get `isFollowing = true` which is clearly  not correct because in my data, there is only 2 values that are true as seen above, not all 3.  The confusing thing is how come I can't retrieve the `Boolean` correctly. I have tried to do `Boolean isFollowing = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.getValue(Boolean.class)` also but this doesn't work. The Firebase documentation says that when retrieving data, a `Boolean` can be a type of data we can retrieve but I can't seem to retrieve it correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for the lack of clarity. I have included what my JSON for that database call looks like. Thanks for helping me make my post more clear! Any idea why this might be happening for me?

Comment: In the JSON you just posted, the `people` node is *under* the `users` node (so `/users/people`). Is that indeed the structure you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me:

```
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/38671701/users");
    Firebase currentUserPath = ref.child("10206287838487450");
    Firebase firebaseRef = ref.child("10206287838487450");
    Firebase followingRef = currentUserPath.child("/following");
    System.out.println("Listening for children on "+followingRef);
    followingRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListenerBase() {
               @Override
               public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                   firebaseRef.child("people/" + dataSnapshot.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                           Boolean isFollowing = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                           System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey()+"="+isFollowing);
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                       }
                   });
               }
     });
```

> Listening for children on https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/38671701/users/10206287838487450/following
>
> 10208425049208936=true
>
> 107214969710378=false
>
> 1789986447904975=true

Comment: Thank you. I think actually I had some problem in my IDE. For some reason a piece of code was never reached and I had to clean/recompile my project to fix it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   Firebase followingRef = currentUserPath.child("following");
   followingRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                  Log.d(TAG, snapshot.getKey();
                  Log.d(TAG, snapshot.getValue();

                 //Do your operations here
              }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Change a model class

**boolean** value
To
**Boolean** value